# Activating tool after cancel button is pressed in message box?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins

I am building a plugin in QGis and I want to activate the plugin icon again when user clicks cancel button in the message box.

```
def run(self, checked):
    if checked == True:
        # icon is active
        # do something
    if checked == False:
        # icon is deactive
        reply = QtGui.QMessageBox.question(self.iface.mainWindow(), 'Continue?', 
             'message', QtGui.QMessageBox.Yes, QtGui.QMessageBox.Cancel)
        if reply == QtGui.QMessageBox.Yes:
            # do something
        if reply == QtGui.QMessageBox.Cancel:
            # set the tool icon active again
            # do nothing
```

Maybe my solution is not the best one.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps use something like the following:

```
def run(self, checked):
    if checked:
        # icon is active
        print 'Do something'
    else:
        # icon is deactive
        reply = QtGui.QMessageBox.question(self.iface.mainWindow(), 'Continue?', 
            'message', QtGui.QMessageBox.Yes, QtGui.QMessageBox.Cancel)
        if reply == QtGui.QMessageBox.Yes:
            # do something
            print 'Yes'
        else:
            # set the tool icon active again
            # do nothing
            self.your_icon.setChecked(True)
```